# Find radius of convergence for $\boldsymbol{\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}x^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

> I need to find radius of convergence for :
>
> $$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}x^n$$

---

My attempt to find the radius of convergence is as follows:

\begin{align}
R &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}\right| \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\sin(\frac{1}{n+1})}\right|\\
&=?\end{align}

I don't know how to find this limit.

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\ln(n)}\cdot \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac1n}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}\cdot \frac{\ln (n+1)}{\ln n}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}\to1\cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot 1=1$$

Note also that

- for $x=1,\; $ the series diverges by ratio test with
  $\;\dfrac{1}{n\ln n}$
- for $x=-1,\; $ the alternating series converges by Leibniz's test

Comment: Very nice. +1${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your appreciation :)

Comment: @DonAntonio I've updated the answer, I think it was wrong for the case x=-1!